# Make git diff not to print to terminal

Tags: git, less-unix

If I do `less somefile.txt` or `man bash` (which uses `less` internally), it displays the content, but after pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>, the content disappears.

`git diff` also uses `less`, but the output remains in console. How can I make `git` act the same as `man`?

---

Current behavior

```
me@mypc:~$ git diff
# I look at the diff and then press q. But it's all printed to the console
diff --git a/somefile.txt b/somefile.txt
...
...
...
me@mypc:~$
me@mypc:~$ less somefile.txt
# I look at the file content, but after I press q, console appears and nothing is printed there
me@mypc:~$
```

I realized that the git behavior is like `less -X`, so how can I force git to run less without that option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the effect of `less -F -X`; see `core.pager` in `git-config(1)`.

From `less(1)`:

```
   -F or --quit-if-one-screen
          Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be dis‐
          played on the first screen.

   -X or --no-init
          Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
          strings  to  the  terminal.   This is sometimes desirable if the
          deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like  clear‐
          ing the screen.
```

Part of the "init" mentioned here involves switching to the alternate screen, so that the main screen is preserved.

---

From `git-config(1)`:

```
   core.pager
       Text viewer for use by Git commands (e.g., less). The value is
       meant to be interpreted by the shell. The order of preference is
       the $GIT_PAGER environment variable, then core.pager configuration,
       then $PAGER, and then the default chosen at compile time (usually
       less).

       When the LESS environment variable is unset, Git sets it to FRX (if
       LESS environment variable is set, Git does not change it at all).
       If you want to selectively override Git’s default setting for LESS,
       you can set core.pager to e.g.  less -S. This will be passed to the
       shell by Git, which will translate the final command to LESS=FRX
       less -S. The environment does not set the S option but the command
       line does, instructing less to truncate long lines. Similarly,
       setting core.pager to less -+F will deactivate the F option
       specified by the environment from the command-line, deactivating
       the "quit if one screen" behavior of less. One can specifically
       activate some flags for particular commands: for example, setting
       pager.blame to less -S enables line truncation only for git blame.

       Likewise, when the LV environment variable is unset, Git sets it to
       -c. You can override this setting by exporting LV with another
       value or setting core.pager to lv +c.
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but 1) it happens even for long files (I realized it's because of less -X) and 2) how can I disable it?

Comment: Add `-+X` as well as the `-+F` mentioned.

Comment: Or by `export LESS=R`. Ok, that's solution of my question. But I have another one: now, less opens even short inputs (like `git config -l`), instead of printing them -FX. How can I keep this behavior but open longer files with less without printing to console? I'm pretty sure this question (and answer) exists, but couldn't find any...

Comment: Ah, in that case you *do* want to keep `-F`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't... I have less v487, which doesn't print anything with `-F`. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432254). But there are workarounds in that question, so I use them... Anyway, your answer answers my original question, so accepting.